# rebol / red parse with [to end] rule

Tags: rebol, red

I'm trying to understand parse from the ground up so don't tell me to use split in this case.

```
sentence: "This is a sentence"

parse sentence [
    any [
        [any space] copy text [to space | to end] skip
        (print text)
    ]
 ]
```

Why do I not get the last word in the sentence, and only:

```
This
is
a
```

Did the `[to end]` not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`to end` did work, but then you have `skip` there and you're already at the end, so `skip` fails. See this:

```
>> parse sentence [any [[any space] copy text [to space | to end ] (print text) skip]]
This
is
a
sentence
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution without to and end

```
sentence: "This is a sentence"
space:  charset " "
chars: complement space

parse sentence [
    any [
       any space 
       copy text some chars
       (print text) 
    ]
]
```

In Rebol2 you have to use parse/all, if you deal with strings, but the most simple solution in Rebol2 for splitting is

```
>> parse sentence none
== ["This" "is" "a" "sentence"]
```